# Parsing JPEG markers with attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

As a project to further my knowledge and comfort with Haskell I am working towards implementing a JPEG decoder which will come in handy for future computer vision work.

The first step I have chosen is to parse all "Markers" within the image.  These are indicated by the byte 0xFF followed by a non-0 byte.  A 0xFF byte followed by a 0x00 byte shall be treated as normal data.

The problem I am running into is that upon encountering a 0xFF 0x00 combination, parsing seems to finish completely and no more valid markers are found (if you run on a standard JPEG you will see the start of image marker parsed, but not the end of image marker as often 0xFF 0x00 occurs within the image data itself).

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO

import Control.Applicative hiding (many)
import Data.Attoparsec as A
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

parseMarker = do
  part1 <- word8 0xFF
  part2 <- notWord8 0x0
  return (part1, part2)

parseSection = do
  A.skipWhile (\x -> x /= 0xFF) *> parseMarker

parseBody = do
  many parseSection

parseJPEG jpeg = do
  handleParseResult $ feed (parse parseBody jpeg) BS.empty

handleParseResult result = do
  case result of
    Fail _ _ msg -> msg
    Done _ r -> show r
    _ -> ""

main = do
  (filename : _ ) <- getArgs
  handle <- openFile filename ReadMode
  contents <- BS.hGetContents handle
  putStrLn $ parseJPEG contents
  hClose handle
```

https://gist.github.com/767488

Comment: IMO, you should post your code inline here.  It's not *that* long and makes it easier to reply to.

Comment: Good point, next time I will make sure to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `parseMarker` consumes input but may fail partway through, you have to be able to "rewind" and retry a different parse when you encounter an 0xFF 0x00.

I don't have Attoparsec installed but I assume it is similar to Parsec which doesn't backtrack by default.

```
parseSection =
    skipMany (notWord8 0xFF <|> try (word8 0xFF >> word8 0x0)) >> parseMarker
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works great and makes a lot of sense.  I had attempted to use try at one point, but due to not handling the 0xFF 0x0 case it of course failed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't tell it to parse a sequence of 0xFF,0x00, it's late so hopefully the next answerer will put words to it (it perhaps it helps you enough), but here is an alternate `parseMarker` and accompanying `handleParseResult`:

```
parseMarker = do   -- or call it "parsePotentialMarker"
  part1 <- word8 0xFF
  part2 <- anyWord8
  return $
    if (part2 /= 0)
        then [(part1, part2)]
        else []

-- ... skipping other functions...
handleParseResult result = do
  case result of
    Fail _ _ msg -> msg
    Done _ r -> show (concat r)
-- ...
```

On a side note, in questions it helps slightly to have a fully functional test in the code, something like:

```
main =
  let contents = BS.pack [1,2,3,4,0xFF,1 {- marker 1 -},0xFF,0x00,0xFF,2 {- marker 2 -},31,13,0xFF,0x00]
  in putStrLn $ parseJPEG contents
```